# Changing width of TabIndicator in View Pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a viewPager.And i Have included  the PagerTabStrip to have text and indicator below text.But the indicator's width is more than the text's width.I want to make the indicator's width same as text's width.How can i achieve that?

[image: Please refer the pic.]
Thanks